# rails4 multiple record updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

The following controller action is a failing under rails 4.2 while it functions in rails 3.2

```
params[:inventoris_for_product].each do |id, inventori_params|
  @inventori = Inventori.find(id)
  @inventori.update_attributes(inventori_params)
end
```

even though a private method  enables the strong params

```
def inventori_params
  params.require(:inventori).permit(:product_id, ...)
end
```

ActiveModel returns the `ForbiddenAttributesError`

Submitted parameters are in the form `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "inventoris_for_product"=>{"2140"=>{"quantity"=>"4", "price_1"=>"45.0" [...]`

Overriding is possible,

```
params[:inventoris_for_product].each do |id, attrs|
  @inventori = Inventori.find(id)
  unlocked_attrs = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(attrs)
  @inventori.update_attributes(unlocked_attrs)
end
```

but not desired.

What am I missing with the new syntactic approach?

Comment: Your not actually using your strong params there, your just using the params hash: `params[:inventoris_for_product]`

Comment: I fail to see the point. `params[:inventoris_for_product]` is to instantiate an array which will get looped through.  Each iteration would then actually  `update` the declared params.

Comment: The block argument `inventori_params` is overriding your strong params

Comment: Right.  I realized that when migrating from 3.2 where `attrs` was invoked (each do |id, attrs| ... update_attributes(attrs).  I'm still not clear how I can run this loop under the strong params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting the controller action with

```
@inventori.update attrs.permit(:quantity, :price_1[...])
```

does the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you means to update multiple records, you can try link this:

```
Inventori.where(id: [1, 2, ...]).update_all(attr_name: val)
```

Comment: `Inventori.where(id: params[:inventoris_for_product][:id].to_a).update_all(attr_name: val)` complains with `undefined local variable or method 'val'`